# Is a power of attorney (in my parent's hands) enough to unfreeze a frozen US bank account?

Tags: banking, power-of-attorney

If somebody has to move to Europe from the US, and cannot return, and then has his US bank accounts frozen:

1. Can he give a power of attorney to his parents (European citizens, only European passport, but no US IDs) to fly to the US and unfreeze the accounts?
2. Will the US banks accept that to unfreeze?
3. Is there a specific form of power of attorney to do that, anyone could share?

Comment: I agree that the reason the accounts were "frozen" would matter. For example, if the accounts are frozen due to a garnishment or a civil forfeiture order or some other court order, they could not be unfrozen simply with a POA. But, if they were simply frozen due to account inactivity, they probably could be unfrozen with a POA.

Answer (score 1):

That would probably depend why the accounts are "frozen".

A notarized power of attorney will authorize any person to act in your name in doing business with a bank. Often it is a good idea to call the bank and notify a manager what you want to do so that if they have any special requirements, then you can meet them.

The document itself must be dated and signed and must specify what powers you are granting to the other person. Those powers should be given a time limit. Also, it is a good idea to have the document notarized. If a bank is involved, then an address and account number or numbers are important to identify exactly who you are.

Comment: Note that if the freezing of the accounts is authorised by law, the bank may not be at liberty to unfreeze them, even at the request of a power of attorney.